# HttpClient is removed from Android 6.0, how do i use it with RestTemplate?

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate, spring-android

I have the need to use the HttpClient to set certain parameters while using Spring's RestTemplate.

I currently do this via:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getParams().setSoTimeout(prefs.getServerTimeout());
httpClient.getParams().setConnectionManagerTimeout(3000);
httpClient.getParams().setContentCharset("UTF-8");
httpClient.getParams().setCredentialCharset("ISO-8859-1", )
...
CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
requestFactory.setReadTimeout(prefs.getServerTimeout());

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

The HttpClient currently used everywhere, and for example in the

```
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.getHttpClient()
```

Is pointing to the deprecated one shipped with Android.

**Since it's deprecated, and removed from Android in 6.0, how do i go about continuing to use a HttpClient object with RestTemplate?**

Since they share the same package (org.apache.http.client), i'm not sure how to make this work in pre/post 6.0.

(I tried using httpclient-android and HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory without setting HttpClient, and it then seems to be using CloseableHttpClient. But the method signature is the deprecated HttpClient as mentioned.)

Pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it's dependency explicitly in gradle or add jar but try considering modern options like volley `'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` 
or okHttp `'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'` or you can use Rest-Template for android `'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M3'`.

Comment: Well, i have looked around, but found no good way to set the parameters i need, most importantly specify the charset to use for basic auth credentials. HttpClient is the only place where i've found it.

Comment: How about this in OKHttp ```Request.Builder reqBuilder = new Request.Builder().addHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8")```.

You can have other charsets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory from springframework  (org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) .

override the prepareConnection method to set timeout and other parameters.

```
public class MySimpleClientHttpRequestFactory  extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

   @Override
   protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
    super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
   }
}
```

Then set it to RestTemplate.

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new MySimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(factory)
```